# Inexplicable Crash?

Tags: crash

I am sure the explanation for this is easily apparent to someone who knows what they are looking at. However, that person is not me. So, if you are out there, here is the story. My laptop is a Dell Latitude 7390 2 in 1. I had Windows installed on it at first and started receiving the "blue screen of death" quite regularly. I reinstalled Windows with no improvement. Today I installed Ubuntu and it ran quite well for a bit and then the screen went black to light up no more. I forced a restart and once more am waiting for it to die. I am wondering if, by referring to this log file, someone can tell me what is going wrong. Perhaps the section about Oct  4 21:04 is most revealing? [var/log/syslog text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P6Sy51LytTETfJi6PyIIrkrwY6LFrMnr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you run ramtests, checked your drive's health (SMART check & test), and checked your hardware for issues (cap check & like visual inspection), as your description reads like a hardware issue (*at least to me as written, and you've not mentioned any checks you've performed*).

Comment: You have a lot of errors relating to Xserver. Can you log in and get the standard Ubuntu desktop? If so. opern a terminal and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell` then let us all know the result by editing your question above.

Comment: This must be a hardware issue because two OS's crash.

Comment: I too think it is a hardware issue. But what exactly? It has completed the memtest suite of ram testing tools successfully twice. I also ran Dell's bios system hardware diagnostics tool which it passed just fine. I have also had the bottom off just to make sure all connections are seated correctly. I could not find any obvious abnormalities. I am looking into the xserver thing. Thanks for all your suggestions and sorry it takes me so long to respond.